# Nano Quadcopters Microcontroller and battery

Tags: arduino, quadcopter, raspberry-pi, python

I am looking into building a nano quadcopter, But as i watch more resources and videos i get more confused, regarding some of the things that i hope would be answered here. I am in very basic level of expertise here, i haven't built any robots or quadcopters to be exact.

What i want to know is, when i program a quadcopter say using intel edison chip, how do i power the quadcpter? i could not find that small size battery to move the propellers and start the chip.

Further more what is the procedure i should follow while developing a nano or small quadcopter, i saw a link on instructable that uses python on raspberry pi and then that raspberry pi control the arduino to control the robot. Can it be done only by using raspberry pi itself?

I am getting confused and i would like to know if i have to make small or nano quadcopter what should i be doing to get started?

Most of the latest chip support linux and high level programming language like python, so i hope i can go about programming the entire quadcopter using python or similar high level language and i don't suppose i have to stick with c langauge now. If i am wrong please help me understand the matter, there is high chance that i could be wrong.

Answer (score 2):

If you are just starting out with quadcopters, it might be better if you buy an off-the-shelf quadcopter first.  Then hack it for your needs while learning the ropes.  (i.e. you wouldn't build a car, bike, computer, etc. from scratch if you've never taken one apart, hacked it, and completely understand what every piece is for.  so why do this with a robot?)

I am not sure, but i kind of doubt you will be able to do some of the low-level flight controls in Python.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a Linux based microprocessor you run the risk of tasks being switched at inopportune moments that's why they used an Arduino in the example, you could also try a ESP3266.

I think you would be making a mistake to build a Nano for your first project.  Larger parts are more readily available.

To build any project you need to work out the components and get them working, otherwise you are going to overwhelm yourself:

1. Learn how to program and use Arduino\ESP8266.
2. Learn how to control a motor
3. Learn how to read all the sensors you need
4. Learn how to communicate from the controller to the quadcopter.
5. Learn how to work out how much lift you need.
6. Buy the different motors and batteries you knew you should have brought in the first place.
7. Put it all together.
8. Pray it doesn't crash to badly on its maiden flight.

Hope that helps :)